# How to navgiate to a new page using react router dom with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

I want to navgiate to a new page after the user has logged in. Typically i would use `this.props.history.push("/some_other_page");` However this gives me the following error.

> Property 'history' does not exist on type 'Readonly & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>

**Singin.tsx**

```
interface Props {
    classes: any
}
interface State {
    email: string;
    password: string;
}

class SignIn extends Component<Props, State> {
    constructor(props: Props) {

        super(props);

        this.state = {
            email: "",
            password: "",
        };
    }

    ...

    handleLogin = async (event: any) => {

        event.preventDefault();

        const credentials: ILoginCredentials = {
            email: this.state.email,
            password: this.state.password
        }

        const res = await this.context.login(credentials);

        if (res.status === 201) {
           this.props.history.push("/dashboard");
        }

    }
   ...
}

SignIn.contextType = AuthContext;
export default withStyles(styles)(SignIn)
```

**App.tsx**

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { MuiThemeProvider, createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { AuthProvider, AuthContext } from "./contexts/AuthContext";
import SignIn from "./components/signin/SignIn";
import SignUp from "./components/signup/SignUp";
import Dashboard from "./components/dashboard/Dashboard";

import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';


import './App.scss';


const theme = createMuiTheme({
    palette: {
        primary: {
            main: '#212121',
            contrastText: '#fff',
        },
        secondary: {
            main: "#ffd600",
        }
    }
})

class App extends Component {

    componentDidMount = async () => {

    }

    createRoutes = () => {
        return (
            <Fragment>
                <Route exact path="/" component={SignIn} />
                <Route exact path="/signup" component={SignUp} />
                <Route exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
            </Fragment>
        )
    }

    render() {
        const history = createBrowserHistory();
        return (
            <div className="root">
                <AuthProvider>
                    <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                        <BrowserRouter history={history}>
                            {this.createRoutes()}
                        </BrowserRouter>
                    </MuiThemeProvider>
                </AuthProvider>
            </div>
        )
    }
}


App.contextType = AuthContext;
export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for the `RouteComponentProps` type defined in the @types/react-router-dom library. Without this TypeScript won't be able to interpret the type of the `history` prop.

Import it and change the props you pass to the `React.Component` type to `Props & RouteComponentProps`.

```
import { RouteComponentProps } from "react-router-dom";

class SignIn extends Component<Props & RouteComponentProps, State> {
```

The history prop should then be defined.

Answer (score 0):

The component must receive the history prop from react-router. So it should be a direct child of a Route component, If you want the full history object you can also grab that off context like `router` not `BrowserRouter` for example:

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

import { Router } from 'react-router-dom'
const history = createBrowserHistory();



<MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
  <Router history={history}>
   {this.createRoutes()}
  </Router>
</MuiThemeProvider>
```

Comment: This gives me no overload method error

```
    const history = createBrowserHistory();
   <BrowserRouter history={history}>
                        {this.createRoutes()}
   </BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: I dont understand why we switched from router to BrowserRouter

Comment: This doesent work No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Readonly<BrowserRouterProps>): BrowserRouter', gave the following error.
    Type '{ children: Element; history: History; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<BrowserRouter> & Readonly<BrowserRouterProps> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.